# how to add Repeater "<br />" tag when data binding

Tags: asp.net, repeater, bind

I am using repeater and mytemplate

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <td>
     <asp:ImageButton ID="btnProductImage" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl='<%# GetImage((Xslbay.Data.ProductImage)(Container.DataItem)) %>'
        CommandArgument='<%# GetFullImage((Xslbay.Data.ProductImage)(Container.DataItem)) %>' 
        OnClick="btnProductImage_Click" />
   </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

but i want to add `<br />` if item index =5

Comment: how can i add br tag while repeater is data binding

Comment: or did you mean "if modulus (item index, 5) = 0" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can either try

```
<br runat="server" visible="<%# Container.ItemIndex == 5 %>" />
```

or

```
<%= Container.ItemIndex == 5 ? "<br/>" : "" %>
```